# How to solve very slow migrations and seeders on Laravel Sail with Apple M1 Max

Tags: mysql, docker, arm64, apple-silicon, laravel-sail

With a brand new Macbook I was a little surprised by the poor performance of my migrations and seeders.

I managed to get MySql 8.0 working on Docker with experimental features enabled and tried to add the platform but it did not make any difference in performance.

Also, I tried MariaDB which supports ARM already but actually it did not make a huge difference and gives me other issues with mysql dumping.

Someone else running into the same problems on the new 2021 M1 chips?

Comment: are you sure it's an m1 issue and not your codes?

Comment: Yes, running on other Macbooks with Intel in 30s and on mine it will last for at least 5 minutes...

Comment: Bind mounts are known to be slow on MacOS; you might double-check that your database data is in a Docker named volume and your code is built into an image, neither bind-mounted from the host.

Comment: Is your Docker running natively, or emulated?

Comment: @Siguza it's running natively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the previous version of Docker I was advised to enable the new Virtualization framework (Experimental Features in settings). This caused MySQL to be really slow.

Conclusion; don't enable the new Virtualization Framework.